# React - State from class to hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

i don't understand something.

From my parents class, i give state to my children class like this :

```
<TrainingArea
   getHtmlGrain={() => this.getHtmlGrain()}
   right={this.state.right}
   grain_language={this.state.lang}
   id_grain={this.state.grain[this.state.currentGrain]}
   skinPath={this.state.training.skin_path}
   selectedBlock={this.state.selectedBlock}
 />
```

and before to take the 'props' in the children class i use this this :

```
this.props.skinPath
```

but now, i don't understand how i can take this props in a 'hook class react'.
Or is not possible?
my parent class look like this :

```js
import TrainingArea from '../Blocks/General/TrainingArea'

class BlockPage extends Component {

state = {
//some state
}

 render() {
   return (
      <TrainingArea
       getHtmlGrain={() => this.getHtmlGrain()}
       right={this.state.right}
       grain_language={this.state.lang}
       id_grain={this.state.grain[this.state.currentGrain]}
       skinPath={this.state.training.skin_path}
       selectedBlock={this.state.selectedBlock}
     />
   )}
```

How I'm using it in my child class :

```js
const TrainingArea = (props) => {
    console.log(props.skinPath)
    return (
       <h1>hi</h1>
    )
}

useEffect(()=> {
    TrainingArea()
})
```

Can someone help me? thx a lot

Comment: what do you mean under 'hook class react'?

Comment: What did you try that didn't work? It's usually as simple as removing the `this` and making sure `props` is the parameter to your function component

Comment: @NikitaMazur functional component  sorry

Comment: You are not using `TrainingArea` correctly. You never call a function component like any other function. You should always be using JSX `<TrainingArea/>`  exactly like you are doing in your class.

Comment: Think about what is happening in your usage: `TrainingArea()` is not passing any parameters, so `props` will be undefined. React will not magically know that you want it to be passed some props.. You have to *give* it props, and use JSX syntax so that it can be rendered correctly.

Comment: In addition, using a component inside a `useEffect` makes no sense. `useEffect` is for **side-effects**, nothing in the effect can ever be rendered to the page.

Comment: i make an update of what i have @BrianThompson

Comment: is just for see the result of my console.log :'(

Comment: That won't work to see the console log. You're console logging props, but not passing it any. If you *really* want to test it that way you'll need to do `TrainingArea({skinPath: 'something'})`, but I don't see why that's useful

Comment: the props 
`skinPath = {this.state.training.skin_path}` 
have the value '/assests/skin.css'

so i have something, but nothing show in my `console.log`

Comment: `useEffect(()=> { TrainingArea() })` will never work as expected. Until we get past that, I don't think we're going to be able to clarify any more.

Comment: ok thank's , i delete the useEffect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically go from this:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const prop = this.props.prop;
        const someState = this.state.someState;
        // ...
        return <button onClick={() => this.setState({ someState: 'state' })}>Example</button>;
    };
}
```

to this:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
    const prop = props.prop;
    const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState();
    // ...
    return <button onClick={() => setSomeState('state')}>Example</button>;
}
```

Comment: Yes if i want to change my parents class, but i want to keep with state for earn time..3

Comment: Assuming you use `<MyComponent prop={123}/>` or similar, `props.prop` will be `123` when being rendered. I guess you were the one that upvoted my answer. If it's the most helpful answer, don't forget to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for take the props

```
const skin= (props) => {
    const [skin, setskin] = useState([...props.skinPath])
}
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to keep props as states

Comment: There's a few issues with this: 1 why put it in state? This is an antipattern. 2 Why would it be an array? The prop was not an array, so why change it's datatype? 3 Components should begin with a capital first letter (`Skin`)

Comment: Yes i know, but i doesn't want to remake all my parents class based on state..

and @BrianThompson you're right sorry

Comment: @Timrenucci I'm not sure what you mean? You don't have to change anything about the parent component to use props in a function component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In your functional component you can access to the provided props as function parameters. For example you can do something like this:

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  console.log(props.skinPath)
}
```

Comment: for me its good to do that but i get this error `Cannot read property 'skinPath' of undefine `

Comment: @Timrenucci This usage of props is no different then the answer you posted yourself, so either your own answer does not work or you are not using this answer as they have instructed.

Comment: @Timrenucci if you got that error then it means that you are not passing the props to the component. You need to pass the props like this `<FunctionalComponent skinPath={skinPath} ...otherProps />`.

Answer (score 0):

susppose you have a parent class like this

```
class Parent extends React.COmponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // some state data
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <TrainingArea
        getHtmlGrain={() => this.getHtmlGrain()}
        right={this.state.right}
        grain_language={this.state.lang}
        id_grain={this.state.grain[this.state.currentGrain]}
        skinPath={this.state.training.skin_path}
        selectedBlock={this.state.selectedBlock}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

and in child component you want some data from props using this

```
const TrainingArea = (props) => {
   console.log(props.skinPath)
   return (
     // render JSX 
   )
}
```

Comment: yes, but when i call TrainingArea in my useEffect function, i get this error :

 `Cannot read property 'skinPath' of undefined`

Comment: @Timrenucci then you should show the code where you are having the problem

Comment: did you import child component (TrainingArea) in Parent component ?